# JFrame Window Edges Are Round on Mac OS 11.0

Tags: java, swing, jframe, macos-big-sur

I've been dabbling with JFrame and usually the window was a rectangle (with sharp edges). After updating to Mac OS 11.0 Big Sur, the JFrame window has round edges. I've looked for how to change the shape of the window, tried `setUndecorated` which basically just shows the content of the frame without the toolbar. I also tried `setShape` which to use it, I had to use `setUndecorated` as well, but it was the same result. It seems to me it's an OS thing, but is there a way to have my frames rectangular without having to use `setUndecorated` (since it does not retain the toolbar of the frame) or maybe I'm using it wrong and I'm missing something in my frame.

[image]

Comment: You can't change the shape of the window without sacrificing the toolbar (i.e. setting the frame undecorated). However why do you even want to make the frame rectangular and go against OS standards by doing so?

Comment: In my frame, I have a JComponent class that I created which has a certain width and height (rectangular shape). Keeping the frame window with round edges will crop my class's edges.

Comment: Instead of trying to change the window shape I would recommend to change the layout of your ui to be compatible with the rounded corners by introducing padding in the corresponding area.